# What's the simplest way to deal with events in C in this situation?

Tags: c, multithreading, event-programming

I'm writing a text-based game, in C.  I want the game to handle NPCs movement and actions in the background, while the user is making his moves.  I'd also use time-based events to tell the user when midnight is (in game-time), or to activate certain things at certain times.

I know that Dwarf Fortress is all single thread stuff, but I can't understand how that's done.  I don't know how he handles events.  Surely he's not polling.

I've never done any thread programming, or anything with sockets.  I've been programming for a while, but I know nothing about those things.

I googled options, but there seems to be a lot of stuff that comes under the heading of event-handling.  I have no idea where to start.  The first idea that comes to mind, is have two separate programs communicating through a text file, but that seems like a very ugly solution.

What's the simplest solution to handle events such as I described?

I'm currently working in Windows but I would switch over to linux if it's easier. I just happened to be using a Windows machine when I started, so it doesn't matter which.

Comment: On which operating system? Please edit your quesiton to improve it.

Answer (score 7):

It is **[operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific** (or hardware specific if you are coding some kernel-like software on the bare metal like an OS kernel -see [osdev.org](http://osdev.org/)-, in *freestanding* C). Stricto sensu you probably cannot write a game in purely standard hosted [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) (*without* using any external library, except the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) using *only* the few functions standardized in C99): you need to use some operating system service.

<sup>I'm focusing on Linux in my answer below.</sup>

If you are coding **on Linux** (in *hosted* C, as all user programs are), you'll **code your [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around a multiplexing [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)** (or perhaps the older [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), which I usually don't recommend; see also [epoll(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html)). Read about the [C10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem). You might use some event loop library like [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) or [libevent](http://libevent.org/).

If you are unfamiliar with most Linux syscalls (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...), read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Reading and polling the terminal is tricky on Linux (because [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)-s are quite complex). You probably want to use some library, like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), to make a terminal application.

If you want to code a GUI application, you'll practically use some [toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) framework like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [Gtk](http://gtk.org/) (or [libsdl](https://www.libsdl.org/)). They provide an event loop, and you'll need to register [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) (read also about [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation), it is a relevant concept).

If you want to have two programs (written by you) communicating, you'll need to use some [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) machinery, notably [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s. You'll probably need some event loop in some (or both) of them.

For time-related issues, [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (so all event loop libraries built above it) is given a delay. See also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html).

I don't recommend using [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)-s in your case ([signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) are an interrupt like abstraction provided by the OS, notably [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) ones). If you do, be very careful, it is tricky. A signal handler is only allowed to call very few async-signal-safe functions, and the usual way is often to simply set some `volatile sig_atomic_t`  flag in it, to be tested and reset inside your event loop. See also [POSIX signal concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04) chapter.

---

If you are coding on a non-[POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) operating system like Windows, you need to learn how to write event loops on it, and what is the low-level system API. You'll probably find some library for that. There exist a few libraries (e.g. [Qt](http://qt.io/)  & [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) - both for and in C++) which are cross-platform. [Windows programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) is very different from POSIX programming, I know nothing about it.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Please stop [bumping the question with minor edits](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/288015/revisions). Almost every link in your answer is unnecessary. This is a software development site, people are expected to know or be able to find out on their own what an operating system is, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use interrupts and timers.

The interrupts indicate:

1. User I/O inputs
2. Timer expiration

Two separate programs could communicate via two pipes or `msgsnd()` or semaphores or mutexes or signals.

(I think there is no need for multiple programs.)

If you write the program so that everything is interrupt driven, along with a 'background' activity that is running when no interrupt is being serviced. Then the program should be 'relatively' easy to implement.

Some experience with real-time embedded program would greatly assist you in the design, coding, debugging and documenting of the program.

Comment: This is mostly true for a kernel-like freestanding system. You don't have *direct* access to IO or interrupts or hardware timer when coding user code to be run under some operating system.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote that answer, because it does not answer the question; it looks like the OP want to code under some operating system (not on the bare metal), and then the above answer is off-topic.